# Issue with nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Following code :

```
def readData():

symbolData = {'20MICRONS':{'CLOSEPRICE':0}}
    
dateWiseStockData = {'20210318': symbolData, '20210319':symbolData}

dates = ['20210318', '20210319']

print(dateWiseStockData)

i = 17

for analysisDate in dates:

    print(analysisDate)

    dateWiseStockData[analysisDate]['20MICRONS']['CLOSEPRICE'] = i
    
    i += 1

print(dateWiseStockData)
readData()
```

Shows following output :

```
{'20210318': {'20MICRONS': {'CLOSEPRICE': 0}}, '20210319': {'20MICRONS': {'CLOSEPRICE': 0}}}
20210318
20210319
{'20210318': {'20MICRONS': {'CLOSEPRICE': 18}}, '20210319': {'20MICRONS': {'CLOSEPRICE': 18}}}
```

Shouldn't this output be :

```
{'20210318': {'20MICRONS': {'CLOSEPRICE': 0}}, '20210319': {'20MICRONS': {'CLOSEPRICE': 0}}}
20210318
20210319
{'20210318': {'20MICRONS': {'CLOSEPRICE': 17}}, '20210319': {'20MICRONS': {'CLOSEPRICE': 18}}}
```

I tried everything but can't get this working.
Is my understanding of nested dictionaries incorrect here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
dateWiseStockData = {'20210318': symbolData, '20210319':symbolData}
```

it's the same dict as value for both keys. I.e. that is the same object, with same id. dicts are mutable so when you change one of them in the loop, you actually change both.

```
symbolData = {'20MICRONS':{'CLOSEPRICE':0}}  
dateWiseStockData = {'20210318': symbolData, '20210319':symbolData}
for key, value in dateWiseStockData.items():
    print(f'{key}:{value}: value id:{id(value)}')
```

output

```
20210318:{'20MICRONS': {'CLOSEPRICE': 0}}: value id:139895906910640
20210319:{'20MICRONS': {'CLOSEPRICE': 0}}: value id:139895906910640
```

One way to do what you want:

```
def readData():
    dates = ['20210318', '20210319']
    dateWiseStockData = {}
    print(dateWiseStockData)
    i = 17
    for analysisDate in dates:
        dateWiseStockData[analysisDate] = {'20MICRONS':{'CLOSEPRICE':i}}
        i += 1
        print(dateWiseStockData)
readData()
```

output

```
{}
{'20210318': {'20MICRONS': {'CLOSEPRICE': 17}}}
{'20210318': {'20MICRONS': {'CLOSEPRICE': 17}}, '20210319': {'20MICRONS': {'CLOSEPRICE': 18}}}
```

Comment: "dicts are mutable so when you change one of them in the loop, you actually change both."
But they are differentiated by keys right ? That's the purpose of having separate keys isn't it ?

Comment: no, they are same object, i.e. same id. Maybe you need to read about mutable objects like list, dicts, etc. You have same object linked to 2 different keys. I edited my answer to show it.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks for the prompt and accurate answer. Being a newbee , I didn't know this concept. Thanks again. This link helped me understand better : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/mutable-vs-immutable-objects-python/